# How to plot confidence intervals for different training samples

Tags: python, visualization, confidence-interval, variance, wandb

I am working on running training with different divisions of a training set. The plots that I get (using wandb) are fine, but not quite informative in my opinion and high in variance.
[image]

Is there a way to plot the mean of the plots, and then confidence intervals around it? Something similar to the picture below. Alternatively, is there a way to plot variance during training?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can get the plot that you desire if you use `group` by feature of W&B. When you initialize W&B run pass in some value to the `group` argument.

```
run = wandb.init(entity='your-id', 
                 project='your-project-name', 
                 config='config-dict', 
                 group='group-name' # example: training-set-name
                 job_type='train' # what this W&B run is logging
)
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/runs/grouping).

Example plot:

[image]

You can also edit different ways you can group the experiments.
[image]

On a side note: You can use different smoothing methods as well. Documentation [here](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/app/features/panels/line-plot/smoothing).

Comment: hi @ayush, could you please update your links?

Comment: The links are updated to reflect the recent changes made to the documentation. Thank you for pointing out @dallonsi.